# Batch file to check files with same name

Tags: batch-file

I've a folder where every archive file has a correspondant image file with the same name. If ordered by file name then the structure of the folder is:

- Folder

  - File1.zip
  - File1.jpg
  - File2.zip
  - File2.jpg
  - **File3.zip** *(this file should be moved to a subfolder)*
  - File4.zip
  - File4.jpg

If the archive file has not its image file then it should be moved to another folder.

One problem is that not all archive files are .zip, but also .rar or 7z and not all images are .jpg but also .jpeg or .png

It would be great if you could point me to the solution because I'm a web designer and .bat files are not really my domain :)

Comment: What's your operating system? Windows, I suppose (you're talking about .bat files)

Comment: Hi RobertKock, yes this is Windows.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you have trouble with? Regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Please read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [SO] isn't a script writing service, I did find the task interessent.
Adapt the pathes in line 2+3 in the following batch to your environment.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal 
PushD "X:\folder\to\check"
Set "MoveToFolder=Y:\move\arc\to"
For /f "delims=" %%Z in ('Dir /B *.zip *.rar *.7z') Do (
  Set "FoundPic="
  For /f "delims=" %%P in (
    'Dir /B "%%~nZ*" ^| findstr /i "\.jpg$ \.jpeg$ \.png$" '
  ) Do Set FoundPic=yes
  If not defined FoundPic echo Move "%%Z" "%MoveToFolder%"
)
PopD
```

Comment: Thank you LotPings. I will be happy to return the favor on [SO] by helping other people with what I know better. About the code, I think there's a small problem because now it's moving all archive files, with or without corresponding images. But this is exactly what I was looking for, that points me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry there is a typo in `findstr`, I'll correct it. Try again.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still moving all archive files.

Comment: Another missing `'` not my day :-( I inserted an echo infront of the move, so you can check - if all works properly remove the echo.

Comment: Row 5 - change `FounPic` to `FoundPic` and it works perfectly! Thanks again!