# Batch file check same filename with other extension in folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can somebody help me with this problem.
My question is simular to this one, but I need it to work also in subdirs.
[Batch file to check files with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973252/batch-file-to-check-files-with-same-name)

So in short, there are files exported from a program (.XCS extension) to a folder with subfolders.
First I call a tool (xconverter) to transform the files in pgmx.
And then I want to check if the PGMX file is generated, because if there's an error inside the XCS, the converter will not make the pgmx. So the verification is like this, test1.xcs goes in, and I want to check if test1.pgmx comes out in the folder after conversion. If the pgmx file is not generated, the corresponding xcs must be moved to an 'error' folder that's inside the folder where the xcs was located and has .err extension after moving them so it is clear the file is not OK.

I searched for some hour's, the code like below works if there's only one file in the folders, but the moment there are more xcs files where the pgmx is not generated, the batch gives 'path not found' errors because it seems to search the xcs files that are already copied to the 'error' folder.

In addition, but not necessary, It should be great if the batch can create a log file (txt) with the names of the XCS files that are not converted to pgmx.

The code I have now:

```
set PROG=C:\Program Files (x86)\SCM Group\Maestro\XConverter.exe
set TOOL=C:\Program Files (x86)\SCM Group\Maestro\tlgx\def.tlgx
set DIR=%%~df%%~pf
set ERF=Error
set MoveToFolder=%DIR%%ERF%\

echo Delete old pgmx files

DEL /S /Q *.pgmx

echo start conversion

for /R %%f in (*.xcs) do (
                echo "%%f"
Call "%PROG%" ^
-s -m 3  ^
-i "%%f" -t "%TOOL%" -o "%DIR%%%~nf.pgmx" -m 0^              

PushD %DIR%
For /f "delims=" %%Z in ('Dir /B *.xcs') Do (
  Set "FoundPgmx="
  For /f "delims=" %%P in (
    'Dir /B "%%~nZ*" ^| findstr /i "\.pgmx$" '
  ) Do Set FoundPgmx=yes
  If not defined FoundPgmx (
    echo Error in %%f
    if not exist %MoveToFolder% md %MoveToFolder%
    move %%Z "%MoveToFolder%%%~nf.err" )
PopD
)
)

echo pgmx created
```

---

SOLVED

---

Final code:

```
@ECHO OFF

Title XCS 2 PGMX

set PROG=C:\Program Files (x86)\SCM Group\Maestro\XConverter.exe
set TOOL=U:\Accord 25\Tlgx\def.tlgx

echo ----------
echo start Conversion
echo ----------

DEL /S /Q *.pgmx

for /R %%f in (*.xcs) do (
                echo "%%f"
Call "%PROG%" ^
-s -m 3  ^
-i "%%f" -t "%TOOL%" -o "%%~pf%%~nf.pgmx" -m 0^              
                )

echo ----------
echo PGMX Generated
echo ----------
echo ----------
echo Start verification
echo ----------


DEL /S /Q errorlog.txt
rmdir /s /Q "%~dp0\error"

md error

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /R %%a in (*.xcs) do (
    if not exist %%~pa%%~na.pgmx (
    SET CDIR=%%~pa%
    SET _CDIR=!CDIR:~1,-1!
    for %%i in ("!_CDIR!") do (SET ParentFolderName=%%~nxi
        move "%%a" "%~dp0error\!ParentFolderName!_%%~na.err" 
        echo %%a >> %~dp0errorlog.txt
   ) 
  )
 )

ENDLOCAL

DEL /S /Q *.xcs

cd %~dp0/error
ren *.err *.xcs
cd ..
rmdir "%~dp0/error"

timeout -t 5
```

Comment: Concerning `set DIR=%%~df%%~pf`: this cannot be done outside of the `for` loop since its meta-variable `%%f` does not exist there...

Comment: @aschipfl I know, but because the  `DIR` parameter is only used inside the `for` loop, `%%f`  exists there I assume?

Comment: Well, the `DIR` variable is not used in the loop but before (at `pushd`); if it was, it would probably work, but I would still not do that, because it is quite confusing...

Comment: It is indeed confusing, but I don't know how to make the batch so it works correctly, do you have any idea how I can modify it?

Comment: Does the converter set an exit code that indicates success or failure?

Comment: No, Unfortunately not. So I think it's the only way to compare input and output filenames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this! It doesn't rename the files, though. That's unnecessary since they will be listed in the log file.

```
for /R %%a in (*.xcs) do (
    if exist %%~paerror if not exist %%~pa%%~na.pgmx (
        copy /b %%a %%~paerror
        echo %%a >> %%~palog.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi @Henrik4, I tried with this code but it doesn't seem to work. After one pgmx is missing, all other XCS files are copied tot error also. In the log all xcs are mentioned, also the good ones. The reason I change the name is because when I leave it as XCS, the first `for` recognizes the xcs in the error folder again leading to a never ending batch...

Comment: @XavierJC Hi there! You must have command extensions enabled to run this. Check it! The code above doesn't take the files in the error folder, only the present folder so renaming is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it works indeed but only in the same folder. I need this to work in the subfolders too. So If i have folderA , it must check if xcs files are found and if the corresponding pgmx is there, but also in folderA\subfolderB and folderA\subfolderC, ... I changed the code a bit because the files ware not copied but renamed to error without extension in the code you writed above. I had now `for %%a in (*.xcs) do (
    if not exist %%~na.pgmx (
 if not exist %%~da%%~paerror md %%~da%%~paerror
 move %%a "%%~da%%~paerror\%%~na.xcs" 
        echo %%a >> log.txt
    )
)`

Comment: @XavierJC I see. Well, that changes the matter. Do you want an error folder in every subfolder? Maybe it's better to skip the error folder and only use the log file? See the new suggestion.

Comment: The Idea of creating an error folder in every subfolder and leave the file extension .xcs is good because if the xcs is not translated into a pgmx, I can import the xcs manually in the software and then it gives more details why it is not converted. The problem I have then is that the `for /R` command recognizes the xcs inside the error folder again, and because the pgmx is not there, it will recreate again an error, so it ends in a loop. The easiest way to solve this is create the error folder in another location, but it's not wat I want. It's easier to find in the same folders

Comment: @XavierJC My last suggestion.

Comment: Super, thanks! I managed to get everything working. to avoid the loop while searching the XCS files (founding the ones already replaced to error) I moved them first with renaming to .err, and then renamed them to .XCS after verification.